# lQuery: Select children by Index() including parent

Tags: jquery, indexing, attr

I want to dynamically get the index of all children with a certain attribute. I can do that like this

```
$("#parent [attribute]:eq(4)");
```

But sometimes the "`#parent`" itself also has the attribute, so I would like to get the index of that parent as well, relating to all the attribute elements index.

I tried this but for some reason it doesn't work

```
$("#parent").find("[attribute]:eq(4)").andSelf();
```

Comment: What is your goal? What is it that you want to do; maybe there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine the selector with a comma `,` :

```
$("#parent [attribute]:eq(4), #parent[attribute]:eq(4)");
```

`andSelf()` method will only select #parent as a selector not `#parent[attribute]:eq(4)`

---

You can do this way too:

```
$("#parent [attribute]:eq(4)").add("#parent[attribute]:eq(4)");
```

Look thorough the api of [add](http://api.jquery.com/add) and [andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf) method.

Comment: This seemed to work at first, but then I noticed that its getting the index of -1 for the children, and the parent z-index is 0 which is right, but the children z-index is wrong.

Comment: sorry, cannot get you.